# Asymptotic number of zeros for Dirichlet series with functional equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, selberg-class

I think [the usual proof for the asymptotic number of zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Location_of_the_zeros) of the Riemann zeta function
$$N(T) = \#\left\{\rho : \ \zeta(\rho)=0, \begin{array}{l}\scriptstyle Im(\rho)\ \in\ [0,T]\\ \scriptstyle Re(\rho) \ \in\ (-1,2)\end{array}\right\}  = \frac{ T\ln T}{2\pi}-\frac{1+\log 2\pi}{2\pi}T+\mathcal{O}(\ln T)$$
 works for any Dirichlet series in the **extended Selberg class $S^{\#}$** (for the Selberg class it is a well-known result), that is Dirichlet series having a functional equation with gamma factors, and being analytic except possibly a pole at $s=1$. More precisely :

- $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ converges absolutely on $Re(s)>1$, and $F(s) (s-1)^m$ is entire of finite order,
- with $\gamma(s) = Q^s\prod_{j=1}^{k} \Gamma(\omega_j s+\mu_j), \omega_j > 0$ and
  $\Phi(s) = \gamma(s)F(s) : \quad \Phi(s) = \xi\, \overline{\Phi(1-\overline{s})}$

Then 
$$N_F(T) = \frac{d_F}{2\pi} T \ln T+\frac{c_F}{2\pi} T+\mathcal{O}(\ln T), \qquad d_F=\sum_{j=1}^m \omega_j, \quad c_F = \ln |Q|^2-1-\ln 2 d_F$$
where $N_F(T) = \#\left\{\rho : \ F(\rho)=0, \begin{array}{l}\scriptstyle Im(\rho)\ \in\ [0,T]\\ \scriptstyle Re(\rho) \ \in\ (-\delta_F,1+\delta_F)\end{array}\right\}$ is the number of zeros, and $ \delta_F$ is chosen such that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty |a_n| n^{-1-\delta_F} < |a_1|$ i.e. $\text{arg}(F(1+\delta_F+it) = \mathcal{O}(1)$

**Questions :**

- Do you have a reference confirming this ? And if I missed something, what additional hypothesis on $F(s)$ are needed ?
- That the asymptotic number of zeros depends on the functional equation not on the Euler product, what does it tell us, about $\zeta(s)$ and the L-functions ?

  *The asymptotics for the zeros allow us to write $\frac{F'}{F}(s) = \sum_{|Im(\rho)-t)| < A} \frac{1}{s-\rho}+\mathcal{O}(\ln t)$ in the critical strip, and then to look at how different constraints (Euler product, growth rate estimates for $F,F',1/F$) interact with those density of zeros. Assuming the GRH, we are probably also allowed to make some general statements about the number of zero crossings of $\Phi(1/2+it)$, and to link it to some properties of modular forms on $Re(\tau) =0$.*
- What happens if I add to $S^{\#}$ the constraint that there is some $l$ such that $\frac{1}{\zeta(\sigma)^l} < |F(s)| \le \zeta(\sigma)^l$ for every $Re(s)=\sigma > 1$ ?

  (*it could mean that $F(s)$ has an Euler product of the form $\prod_{j=m}^l \prod_p (1-\alpha_{j}(p)p^{-s})^{-1}$* where $|\alpha_j(p)|\le 1$)

Answer (score 3):

The von Mangoldt-type formula for this class of L-functions was alredy stated without proof by Selberg himself in his paper:

- Atle Selberg, "Old and new conjectures and results about a class of Dirichlet series" (1989)

The precise statement is

$$N(T)=\frac{d}{2\pi}T\log T+cT+O(\log T)$$

where $d$ is the degree of $F$ and $c$ is some constant depending on $F$.

Note that it is stated for what we know call $S^{\#}$, not for $S$.

The proof is essentially the same as for $\zeta(s)$. You can see a sketch on Li Zheng's survey on the Selberg class.

I'm not sure what to make of the second or third question, but I'm confident that the answer to the second is "nothing". Perhaps you can elaborate on what dependence you expected between $N(T)$ and the Euler product.

Comment: ok then do you have a reference, a link ?

Comment: @user1952009 Sure. I've edited to include it.

Comment: I can't find Selberg's paper, and in Li Zheng's concise survey it is only about $S$, not $S^{\#}$

Comment: @user1952009 Perhaps you have better luck finding the 2nd volume of Selberg's collected works. I haven't been able to find the Amalfi Proceedings (where it first appeared) myself.

Comment: http://publications.ias.edu/selberg has the Amalfi lecture(s).

Comment: I don't understand why you let the [Li Zheng reference](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/teaching/613-Winter2011/SelbergClass.pdf). Selberg in [his original article](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Selberg%20-%20original%20paper%20on%20Selberg%20and%20extended%20Selberg%20class%20-%201989.pdf) p.48 states what I wrote without proof, do you have other references where it is stated ? And where it is proved ? 
And in http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/DOCamalfiX.pdf it is  stated again without a complete proof

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. Selberg is a reference for the result; Zheng a reference for the proof. For example [Murty](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9407219) also quotes the result. I doubt anyone has bothered to write down and publish a full proof.

Comment: @Myshkin I asked it 10 times : Where do you see Zheng mentions the result **for $S^{\#}$ and proves it** ? And no, Murty mentions only the result for $S$

Comment: And if nobody proves the result and make it clear this is an obvious result for $S^{\#}$, then it is a problem. For example, myself I know quite well the subject (for a non-professional), and I noticed this only yesterday. So we have to make it clear, for example adding a section in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class about $S^{\#}$ and this result

Comment: @user1952009 the proof is the same for $S^{\#}$ as it is for $S$, and it only uses elementary analytic number theory. I don't really see the problem.

Comment: Come on, did you read my question ? Yes I know the proof is the same, that's what I wrote in my question. The problem is that almost nowhere it is stated clearly that it is a result for $S^{\#}$, and nowhere it is proven with the assumption $F \in S^{\#}$ made clear.

Comment: And please, look at [Li Zheng, a concise survey of the Selberg class of L-functions, page 9](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/teaching/613-Winter2011/SelbergClass.pdf) you'll see his proof doesn't work for $F \in S^{\#}$, since he states that $\text{arg}F(2+it) = \mathcal{O}(1)$ and $N(T)$ is the number of zeros in $Re(s )\in (0,1)$, which is not correct for $F \in S^{\#}$

Answer (score 3):

Also, there is a paper by Bombieri and Hejhal, from 1995 in Duke Math. J., that shows that under a modest GRH linear combinations of the two unramified ideal-class character L-functions of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ have lots of off-the-line zeros. One point is that the two have the same Gamma factors, and the same functional equation, so any linear combination does, as well. Yes, the same argument-principle discussion tells the asymptotics of the number of zeros up to height $T$, and it is the same for linear combinations...

In fact, similar linear combinations and integrals of L-functions give Epstein zeta functions, which Potter-Titchmarsh and others have shown have many off-line zeros. The asymptotic zero-counts to height $T$ are as expected, but quite a lot of zeros are off-the-line.

So, for example, the functional equation alone is insufficient to have any hope of truly all zeros on-the-line. (I gather that it is not impossible that asymptotically 100\% are on-the-line...?)

Comment: of course, I never said there is a RH for those

Comment: @user1952009, no, indeed, but/and I have the impression that there is a general folkloric belief in such directions that is too optimistic... so, with the excuse of responding to your question... :)

Comment: But looking at the articles, it seems there are some deep conjectures about those, about the density of zeros $Re(\rho) \ge \sigma$ for $\sigma \ge 1/2$.

Comment: @user1952009, yes, indeed, there appear to be subtleties about even the zeros of linear combinations of Euler products, etc. Also, in case one hadn't happened to think of it or hear about it, Landau and Hecke and Siegel and others noted Euler products with nice functional equations under $s\to 1-s$) that have _no_ zeros on-the-line (e.g., the classic $\zeta(2s)\zeta(2s-1)$). Various other natural "periods" of Eisenstein series (e.g., along $O(n)$ on $O(n,1)$) tend to have zeros farther off the critical line as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant implicitly in my question : $S^{\#}$ is (more or less) the set of Mellin transforms of modular/automorphic forms. For example $F(s) = \zeta(s)\zeta(s+2k-1)$ is the Mellin transform of  $E_{2k}(ix)-1$ the Eisenstein series,  and $F(2k s)\in S^{\#}$. Clearly its zeros are in $Re(s)\in (0,1/2k) \cup (1-1/2k,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

See the theorem 2.15 in the survey of the Selberg class by Li ZHENG.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265103975_A_CONCISE_SURVEY_OF_THE_SELBERG_CLASS_OF_L-FUNCTIONS

Comment: my question is about the extended Selberg class, while in https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/teaching/613-Winter2011/SelbergClass.pdf  it seems to be only about the Selberg class

Comment: allo ${}{}{}{}{}$