# Dirichlet series of a lattice $\sum_{a \in \Lambda^*} |\det(a)|^{-s}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, zeta-functions

For a lattice $\Lambda$ of rank $n$ in $\mathbb{Q}^{n\times n}$ whose non-zero elements are inversible matrices, let $$Z(s,\Lambda) = \sum_{a \in \Lambda^*} |\det(a)|^{-s}$$
**I wonder if (and how to show) this Dirichlet series has a functional equation ?**

The motivation is that $\zeta_K(s)$ the Dedekind zeta function of a number field is of the form $\zeta_K(s) =\frac{1}{|\mathcal{O}_K^\times|}\sum_{J \in C_K} N(J)^{s} Z(s,\Lambda_J)$ where $C_K$ is the ideal class group, $\mathcal{O}_K$ [being isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_field) to such a lattice in $\mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}$.

---

Aurel commented that for most number fields $\sum_{a \in \mathcal{O}_K^*} |N(a)|^{-s}$ diverges (infinitely many units), so we have to look at $\sum_{a \in \mathcal{O}_K^*/\mathcal{O}_K^\times} |N(a)|^{-s}$, and on the lattice side, except when $\Lambda$ is (up to a constant) a subring of $\mathbb{Q}^{n\times n}$, it is not obvious how to translate it.

Comment: I assume $\Lambda^*$ means that you exclude all singular matrices.

Comment: I have always thought that Dirichlet series satisfying functional equations must somehow be "motivic", in the very elementary sense that they should be connected to some arithmetico-geometric object having a certain notion of "duality" and that the functional equations reflects this duality. I would be very surprised to realise that an arbitrary $Z(s,\Lambda)$ as above verify such an equation.

Comment: The first series you write does not converge in general since there could be infinitely many elements of $\Lambda$ having the same determinant. The equality you write about the Dedekind zeta function is incorrect for the same reason, unless there your field is $\mathbb{Q}$ or imaginary quadratic.

Comment: @Aurel Do you have an example of such a degenerate lattice ? And $K \simeq \mathbb{Q}(A_1,\ldots,A_m)$ for some matrices $A_l \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}, n = [K:\mathbb{Q}]$. In this matrix field the field norm $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ is  $\det(x)$, so for an ideal $I \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ : $\sum_{a \in I} |N(a)|^{-s} = \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} |det(\lambda)|^{-s}$ for some lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{Q}(A_1,\ldots,A_n)\subset \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, take $\Lambda = \mathcal{O}_K$ where $K$ is a number field with infinite unit group (i.e. any number field that is not $\mathbb{Q}$ or imaginary quadratic). In such an $\mathcal{O}_K$ there are infinitely many elements of norm $1$, and therefore in the corresponding $\Lambda$ there are infinitely many elements of determinant $1$.

Comment: @Aurel Ok I feel dumb... So I have to look at $\Lambda/ \Lambda^\times$ where $\Lambda^\times$ is the set of matrices with $\det = c$, that's what you are saying ?

Comment: @user1952009 watch out that unless $\Lambda$ is a subring, the set of elements with determinant $1$ might not be a subgroup.

Comment: @user1952009 maybe not, but one has to be very careful about the finite-to-one property of the determinant over the lattice. For instance, if the determinant looks like $x_1^{2m}+\dots+x_n^{2m}$ on a basis of your lattice, the definition makes sense.

Comment: @Aurel Tks. I must admit I looked at the lattice point of view because it is natural to look at the Poisson summation formula for those, but I didn't except I had to work much more on the kind of lattice. I'll work on this  [Minkowski space proof (p.9)](http://kskedlaya.org/Math254B/zetafunction.pdf) of the functional equation for $\zeta_K(s)$. Yes with this kind of determinant it reduces to the Poisson summation formula for $\sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 x}$

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo, analytic continuation and functional equation are much more broad than motivic things. For example, Epstein zeta functions have analytic continuations and functional equations, but ... at the very least because there is a continuum of them, with irrational and transcendental parameter data... these are mostly not-at-all motivic.

Comment: @paulgarrett: thanks! I was not aware of this and, as far as I understand, Epstein came up with these $\zeta$ functions precisely to understand the exact conditions to be put on a Dirichlet series to admit a functional equation, right?

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo, so far as I know, Epstein, Hurwitz, and others were trying to see the potential scope of Riemann's analytic continuation method for zeta and such, perhaps to get some traction on RH, perhaps imagining that looking at "families" of things would be useful.

Comment: @paulgarrett IMO, looking at families of functions very similar to $\zeta(s)$ but for which the RH fails is the easiest way for ruling out some approaches to the RH. For example [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253319/asymptotic-number-of-zeros-for-dirichlet-series-with-functional-equation) was totally in this spirit

Comment: @paulgarrett related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205481/functional-equation-for-ray-class-zeta-functions